# How can I use the WriteAllText method to write a new txt file in VS for Mac?

Tags: c#, macos, .net-core

I am following through the "C# Fundamentals for Absolute Beginners" course, specifically the part in lesson 17 where you must create a new text file using the WriteAllText method on mac.

However, when I am writing down the file path, it uses the C: drive but I am on a mac, so I have no C: drive. I have attempted to change this to the name of my hard drive (Macintosh HD), but it has not worked. It always just creates the txt. file in the project file, as opposed to the designated file path.

The TestFolder has already been created in the right directory.

The part I'm referring to: https://youtu.be/2syMt1HQgE0?t=669

Original code from lesson:

```
string text = "A class is the most powerful data type in C#. Like a 
               structure, " +
              "a class defines the data and behavior of the data type. ";

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteText.txt", 
text);
```

My code attempt:

```
string text = "A class is the most powerful data type in C#. Like a 
               structure, " +
              "a class defines the data and behavior of the data type. ";

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"Macintosh HD:\Users\(Username)\Documents\ 
(Filename)\Coding\C#\TestFolder\WriteText.txt", text);
```

I expected the WriteText.txt file to appear in the TestFolder.
Instead, it appears in the Debug folder in the project folder, with the file path as the file name.

Comment: Doesn't OSX use forward slashes as path separator?

Comment: Don't know, let me try that instead. In the Finder it doesn't specify it just uses arrows for the path separators.

Comment: If you print out the value of [`Environment.CurrentDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.currentdirectory?view=netframework-4.7.2) it should show you the expected format for drive and path specifications.

Comment: Please tag with the framework you are using (presumably Mono or .NET Core). The Visual Studio tags are for questions _about_ Visual Studio, not for questions about code written in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following...

```cs
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"/Users/(Username)/Documents/(Filename)/Coding/C#/TestFolder/WriteText.txt", text);
```

Note that Mac paths use forward slashes (`/`) instead of the backslashes (`\`) that Windows uses.

MacOS is a Unix-based operating system that uses a Unix-style filesystem. You can find a brief overview of some of the differences between Windows and Unix filesystems [here, on howtogeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/137096/6-ways-the-linux-file-system-is-different-from-the-windows-file-system/). There plenty more info with a bit of Googling--try "windows vs linux filesystem", which seems to give better results than "windows vs mac filesystem". Keep in mind, though, that MacOS does have still have some differences from Unix--a big one is that Mac systems generally aren't case-sensitive, even though Unix usually is.

If you're comfortable in a terminal, you can always use `cd` to navigate to a folder, and then use `pwd` to print its full path.

Comment: This worked, I had to use forward slashes and eliminate the Macintosh HD part. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your path isn't correct. Just copy and paste there some real path (you can find it in Finder) and it will work.